# I am efforting to send a radio value of input tag in div tag to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I wonder why getElementById doesn't work in radio type.

My HTML code for PHP parsing.

```
  echo "<div id='poll".$i."'> 
    ...
    <input type='radio' name='vote' value='0' onclick='getVote".$i."(this.value)'>
    ...
    <input type='radio' name='vote' value='1'onclick='getVote".$i."(this.value)'>
    </form>
    </div>";
   ...
    <input type='text' name='txtfile' id='txt".$i."' value=".$item_link4." hidden>
```

$i is number given by for loop in PHP. My js code is something wrong with html code. I show you just 1 sample js code and, please see the detail.

```
function getVote23(str) {
  ...
      document.getElementById("poll23").innerHTML=this.responseText;
    }
  }
  var vote = document.getElementById("poll23").value+"  "+document.getElementById("txt23").value+"  "+getCookie("username");
  xmlhttp.open("GET","poll_vote.php?vote="+vote,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

And I have tested the result if the vote value is sent to poll_vote.php.

Next is the first part of poll_vote.php code.

```
$vote = $_GET['vote'];
echo $vote;
```

I received the next result.

```
 undefined www.doctorsnews.co.kr-news-articleView.html-idxno=123372 Ohjho
```

Why null show up? Where does the value of onclick function go out?
Please help me.

Comment: I think `("poll23".value)` should be `("poll23").value`.

Comment: You should provide a [mcve]. Your question is about how JavaScript interacts with HTML. Don't show us PHP, show us HTML. Use the [live demo feature](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Comment: @Syscall Thank you for your tip. I changed that. Now null is replaced by undefined.

Comment: @Quentin Your advice is a model for every question. In my case, How can I show you what the codes are?

Comment: @Syscall No, i want value = 0 or 1.

Comment: @Drohjho — Click edit. Click the snippet button. Following the guidelines at the other end of the link in my previous comment: write HTML in the HTML box and JS in the JS box. Click Run. Make sure it reproduces the problem. Check to see if the act of building the mcve has shown you the solution (and delete or answer the question if it has).  Click Save & Insert into question. Save the edits.

Comment: @Drohjho So, why not use `str`?

Comment: @Syscall 'Cause I receive another values which are composed of strings, eg. txt file name and cookie username. Instead of str, Int is right?

Comment: @Drohjho in `getVote23(str)`, `str` is equals to the `value` attribute of the clicked element, because you're using `getVote".$i."(this.value)`. So `vote=str+' '+document.get...` should work. But maybe I misunderstanding your question.

Comment: @Syscall Thank you for your right answer. That works!!

Comment: @Syscall I didn't think the included parameter in the javascript function. And I regret only wanting the value from  getElementById function.

Answer (score 0):

Change radio name by name='vote'.$i and pass $i on click of radio button to get vote function and no need to generate repeated code for each block so that you can get value of related radio by

```
<form >
    <img src='./imoticon/good.png' style='width:29px;height:29px;'>좋아요:
    <input type='radio' name='vote'.$i value='0' onclick='getVote($i)'>
    <img src='./imoticon/bad.png' style='width:29px;height:29px;'>싫어요:
    <input type='radio' name='vote'.$i value='1'onclick='getVote($i)'>
</form>
function getVote(index) {
  var vote = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="vote'+index+'"]:checked')[0].value+"  "+document.getElementById("txt"+index).value+"  "+getCookie("username");
  xmlhttp.open("GET","poll_vote.php?vote="+vote,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: what is the problem ?

Comment: In getVote23(this.value), this.value is str parameter. But I mistook 'cause of using the getElementById.

Comment: Then just pass str+"  "+document.getElementById("txt23").value+"  "+getCookie("username"); but i changed your code because you are using hard coded ids in your code and in my code you don't need to create multiple getVote functions, Just reuse code. otherwise its your wish.

Answer (score 0):

The Right code is below.

```
var vote = str +"  "+document.getElementById("txt23").value+"  "+getCookie("username");
```

I appreciate Syscall's brief and right answer.

[image]

I didn't cast any downvote ever. But I realized many developers cast that easily and they didn't give any advice nor any answer. 
I don't understand that action.

In oriental proverb,

見指忘月
Every developer will search that meaning easily.